# FFMPEG watermark video without re encoding or losing quality

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'm trying to watermark on video but there is any way to do it without re encoding video for losing quality?

Im trying with simple command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -vf "movie=logo.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [out]"  output.flv
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no, watermark is designed to merge into the video which is not easy to be removed perfectly, so ffmpeg have to decode original video, merge the original video together with watermark logo, and then re-encode it to form a new video clip.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the audio with -c:a copy so it remains the same. 
The video is different with the overlay so you can adjust quality settings as described at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264 .